# Exploratory analysis for multiple regression with a dummy varible

Tags: multiple-regression, exploratory-data-analysis

I currently have a model like this in R:

```
weight ~ age + height + gender
```

So for basic exploratory analysis I made scatter plots of

> weight vs age
>
> weight vs height

Do I also need to do it for gender as well, since I have it coded 1 for male and 0 for female it kinda doesn't make sense to do it. and only makes the data plotted along 2 vertical lines which doesn't tell me anything about the linearity or homoscedasticity for the model assumption

Comment: It could certainly tell you something about potential heteroskedasticity; if the variance for males was five times that of females you'd be likely to see it (as lomg as the sample sizes were not very small)

Comment: @Glen_b, yea I do see a little difference, but it still doesn't say anything about linearity. I need both assumptions to be satisfied before I can check normality right

Comment: I was merely pointing out that you had made a false assertion in your question. ... Linearity in a dichotomous variable is automatic; but you also should consider whether it's possible for there to be interactions between predictors.  (preferably all such considerations precede data collection)